# useState in react not pushing into my array first try

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to push values to an array with usestate, always have an empty array first !

After a while i decide to providse the entire runnable code and hope someone can help

```
const Tasks = () => {
  const [task, setTask] = useState('');
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);

    const addTask = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setTasks([
      ...tasks,
      {
        id: tasks.length,
        description: task,
      },
    ]);
    setTask('');
  };
return (
    <form
      onSubmit={addTask}
      noValidate
      autoComplete="off"
    >
      <TextField
        value={task}
        id="standard-basic"
        label="Type and Enter to add a task"
        onChange={(e) => {
          setTask(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
    </form>
  );
};
export default Tasks;
```

[Codesandbox runnable code here](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-sanne-m5ynf?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Could you provide a runnable code that can reproduce your issue? Your state update logic seems okay to me

Comment: done, here is my code

Comment: Please make a simple example and deploy on codesandbox, your code doesn't seem problematic.

Comment: I tested your code and it worked, I don't see what is the problem?

Comment: It doesn't work on first hit enter and returns empty array

Comment: You were Right I display the data in a list and no problrem, I Thing my console log of my array was not well placed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
    const addTask = (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault()
    const newTask = {
    id:tasks.length,
    description:task
    }
    setTasks((prevState)=>[...prevState,newTask])
    setTask("")
     }
```

Comment: I tried your code and still have an empy array on first enter

Comment: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-snow-72lp8?file=/src/App.js) you can check here how it works.

Comment: Your code worked and my code was also working, When I display the data in a list in jsx it works fine, I Think I console.log my array in a wrong place see code sandbow above

Comment: I hope it is working now.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you did not update your state correctly. Use function like this if your new state depends on old one.

```
   setTasks(prevState => [
      ...prevState,
      {
        id: prevState.length,
        description: task,
      },
    ]);
```